# Subclassing UICollectionViewCell and initialising from xib

Tags: ios, swift

I am registering the cell like this:

```
collectionView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ItemCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ItemCellIdentifier")
```

and accessing it like this:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ItemCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemCell
```

ItemCell is the subclass of UICollectionViewCell:

```
class ItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemImageDescription: UILabel!

    //creation from nib requires this method to be overridden
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Finally I have my xib with a UICollectionViewCell with class ItemCell.

I keep getting the error:

> Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView
>   _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44.2/UICollectionView.m:3443.

The crash is on this line:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ItemCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemCell
```

**EDIT**

```
collectionView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ItemCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ItemCellIdentifier")
```

is called from

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

}
```

contained in:

```
class CollectionCell : UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you calling `registerNib`?

I reproduced the setup to match what i can tell from yours.

This works for me, no errors :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var model:[String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // just a simple test model ...
        for index in 1...100 {
            model.append("\(index)")
        }

        // register the nib
        collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ItemCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell")

        // this is just a test layout
        var layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width:200.0,height:200.0)
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        self.collectionView.delegate = self;
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: -  UICollectionViewDataSource
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
            return model.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
            var cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
            return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Alessandro, your edit says you are calling `registerNib` from what seems to be inside the initialiser of a custom `UITableViewCell` ? I'm sorry this doesn't make any sense at all.  `registerNib` should be called on a `viewDidLoad` method of a `UIViewController`.

Comment: It is actually a UITableViewCell that has inside a collection view

Comment: UICollectionView should only present UICollectionViewCell's. I would suggest to read the documentation on UICollectionView and then re-formulate your setup entirely. What you are doing makes very little sense, makes for very poor quality code and it's no wonder you get an error.

Comment: In your example you are doing the same thing. You are adding a collectionView from a UIViewController. I am adding it from a UITableViewCell

Comment: A UIViewController is a controller. UITableViewCell is a view. In the MVC paradigm those two things are very different and i cannot explain that, do some reading on MVC to understand the difference. In any case, it's hard to say from what you show of your code but if what you are doing is adding a UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell's for some complex layout need then the right place to call registerNib is the viewDidLoad method in the UIViewController that is holding the UITableView. The init() method of a cell will not work well if at all (nor should be attempted if it did).

Answer (score 1):

Try to search in main bundle

```
collectionView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ItemCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ItemCellIdentifier")
```

Answer (score 0):

The crash is because the downcasting has failed. Instead of using forced form as! use the conditional one as?

Try this other way to register cells:

***ViewDidLoad***

```
collectionView.registerClass(ItemCell.self,forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"ItemCellIdentifier")
```

***cellForItemAtIndexPath***

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UICollectionViewCell
{
      var  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ItemCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ItemCell
    cell.titleLabel.text="cellText"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: the compiler forces me to use as!. It says "AnyObject" is not convertible to "itemCell"

Comment: I have edited my answer. My compiler is not forcing me to use as!

Comment: Why are you overriding the initialisers in ItemCell ? You're not actually doing anything in either initializer except calling super, so you don't need to implement either initializer! If you don't override any designated initializers, you inherit all of your superclass's designated initializers.