# Zoomed UIImage inside ScrollView inside CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

My goal is to create app like Apple Photos app - show photos, allow to zoom, scroll from horizontally, etc...
I am currently stuck at allowing to zoom photo in `collectionViewCell`.

What I've done: I have `collectionView` with `scrollView` inside `collectionViewCell`. This is how I create `UIImageView` inside In `CollectionViewController` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
    let imageView: UIImageView!
    let someImage = UIImage(named: "someImage")
    imageView = UIImageView(image: someImage)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), size:someImage.size)

    cell.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    cell.scrollView.contentSize = someImage.size

    let scrollViewFrame = cell.scrollView.frame
    let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / cell.scrollView.contentSize.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / cell.scrollView.contentSize.height
    let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    cell.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;

    cell.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
    cell.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;

    centerScrollViewContents(cell.scrollView, imageView: imageView)
```

(I found this code on [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift))

Next thing I need to add this code, so that zooming would work properly:

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView!) -> UIView! {
    return imageView
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
    let boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    var contentsFrame = imageView.frame

    if contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0
    }

    if contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0
    }

    imageView.frame = contentsFrame
}
```

The thing is, my `IBAOutlet` for `scrollView` is inside `CollectionViewCell`, not `CollectionViewController`, so those two functions have to be called from `CollectionViewCell`, but I don't know how to access `imageView` for `viewForZoomingInScrollView`. Maybe my whole approach is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create UICollectionViewCell **subclass** with xib

[Subclassing UICollectionViewCell and initialising from xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932791/subclassing-uicollectionviewcell-and-initialising-from-xib)

or without xib

http://randexdev.com/2014/08/uicollectionviewcell/

then set **delegate** for **scrollView** is **collectionViewCell** subclass

Add UIScrollViewDelegate code to cell

You can access imageView from cell property